# ubuntu 2. monitor showing up in xrandr, but blackscreen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Probably this question has been answered somewhere, but I have been looking and most of the problems were a little different than mine.

As the title explains I have the following problem:
I have a dell Inspiron 15 with a gtx 1050ti. I installed a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04. I then wanted to run a 2. monitor via HDMI, but when I tried plugging it in, I only got a black screen, so the monitor has a signal, but the screen is black.
My xrandr:

> HDMI-1-1 connected 3440x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 333mm
>      3440x1440     49.99*+
>      2560x1440     59.95
>      1920x1440     60.00
>      2560x1080     60.00    59.94
>      1856x1392     60.01
>      1792x1344     75.00    60.01
>      2048x1152     59.90    59.91
>      1920x1200     59.88    59.95
>      1920x1080     59.97    59.96    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.93
>      1600x1200     75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00
>      1680x1050     74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88
>      1600x1024     60.17
>      1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98
>      1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    60.00    59.82
>      1280x1024     75.02    60.02
>      1440x900      59.89    59.90
>      1400x900      59.96    59.88
>      1280x960      60.00
>      1440x810      60.00    59.97
>      1368x768      59.88    59.85
>      1360x768      59.80    59.96
>      1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
>      1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00
>      1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74
>      1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00
>      960x720       75.00    60.00
>      928x696       75.00    60.05
>      896x672       75.05    60.01
>      1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
>      960x600       59.93    60.00
>      832x624       74.55
>      960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
>      800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
>      840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88
>      864x486       59.92    59.57
>      720x576       50.00
>      800x512       60.17
>      700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98
>      800x450       59.95    59.82
>      720x480       60.00    59.94
>      640x512       75.02    60.02
>      720x450       59.89
>      700x450       59.96    59.88
>      640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94
>      720x405       59.51    58.99
>      720x400       70.08
>      684x384       59.88    59.85
>      680x384       59.80    59.96
>      640x400       59.88    59.98
>      576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06
>      640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
>      512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00
>      512x288       60.00    59.92
>      416x312       74.66
>      480x270       59.63    59.82
>      400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34
>      432x243       59.92    59.57
>      320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05
>      360x202       59.51    59.13
>      320x180       59.84    59.32
>     1920x1080 (0x6c) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1960 total 2000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
>           v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
>     1920x1080 (0x6d) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
>           v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
>     1920x1080 (0x6e) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
>           v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
>     1680x1050 (0x70) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
>           v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
>     1680x1050 (0x71) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
>           v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
>     1600x1024 (0x72) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
>           v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz
>     1400x1050 (0x73) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
>           v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
>     1600x900 (0x74) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
>           v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
>     1600x900 (0x75) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
>           v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
>     1600x900 (0x76) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
>           v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
>     1600x900 (0x77) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
>           v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
>     1280x1024 (0x78) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
>           v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
>     1440x900 (0x79) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
>           v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
>     1400x900 (0x7a) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
>           v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
>     1400x900 (0x7b) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
>           v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
>     1280x960 (0x7c) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
>           v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
>     1440x810 (0x7d) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
>           v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
>     1440x810 (0x7e) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
>           v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
>     1368x768 (0x7f) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
>     1368x768 (0x80) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
>     1360x768 (0x81) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
>     1360x768 (0x82) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
>     1280x800 (0x83) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
>           v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
>     1280x800 (0x84) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
>           v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
>     1280x800 (0x85) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
>           v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
>     1280x800 (0x86) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
>           v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
>     1152x864 (0x87) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
>           v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
>     1280x720 (0x88) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
>           v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
>     1280x720 (0x89) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
>           v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
>     1280x720 (0x8a) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
>           v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
>     1280x720 (0x8b) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
>           v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
>     1024x768 (0x8c) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
>           v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
>     1024x768 (0x8d) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
>     960x720 (0x8e) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
>           v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
>     928x696 (0x8f) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
>           v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
>     896x672 (0x90) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
>           v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
>     1024x576 (0x91) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
>           v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
>     1024x576 (0x92) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
>           v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
>     1024x576 (0x93) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
>           v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
>     1024x576 (0x94) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
>           v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
>     960x600 (0x95) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
>     960x600 (0x96) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
>     960x540 (0x97) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
>           v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
>     960x540 (0x98) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
>           v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
>     960x540 (0x99) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
>           v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
>     960x540 (0x9a) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
>           v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
>     800x600 (0x9b) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
>           v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
>     800x600 (0x9c) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
>     800x600 (0x9d) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
>           h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
>     840x525 (0x9e) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
>           v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
>     840x525 (0x9f) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
>           v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
>     864x486 (0xa0) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
>           v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
>     864x486 (0xa1) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
>           v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
>     800x512 (0xa2) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
>           v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
>     700x525 (0xa3) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
>           v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
>     800x450 (0xa4) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
>           v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
>     800x450 (0xa5) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
>           v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
>     640x512 (0xa6) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
>           v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
>     720x450 (0xa7) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
>           v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
>     700x450 (0xa8) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
>           v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
>     700x450 (0xa9) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
>           v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
>     640x480 (0xaa) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
>           v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
>     640x480 (0xab) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
>           h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
>           v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
>     720x405 (0xac) 22.500MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
>           v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  422           clock  59.51Hz
>     720x405 (0xad) 21.750MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
>           v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  58.99Hz
>     684x384 (0xae) 42.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   684 start  720 end  788 total  892 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
>           v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.88Hz
>     684x384 (0xaf) 36.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
>           v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.85Hz
>     680x384 (0xb0) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
>           v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
>     680x384 (0xb1) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
>           v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
>     640x400 (0xb2) 41.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  676 end  740 total  840 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
>           v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  415           clock  59.88Hz
>     640x400 (0xb3) 35.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
>           v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  411           clock  59.98Hz
>     576x432 (0xb4) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
>           v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
>     640x360 (0xb5) 37.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
>           v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  374           clock  59.86Hz
>     640x360 (0xb6) 31.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
>           v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  370           clock  59.83Hz
>     640x360 (0xb7) 18.000MHz -HSync +VSync
>           h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
>           v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  376           clock  59.84Hz
>     640x360 (0xb8) 17.750MHz +HSync -VSync
>           h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
>           v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.32Hz
>     512x384 (0xb9) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
>           v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
>     512x288 (0xba) 23.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   512 start  532 end  580 total  648 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
>           v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  299           clock  60.00Hz
>     512x288 (0xbb) 21.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
>           v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.92Hz
>     480x270 (0xbc) 20.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   480 start  496 end  544 total  608 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
>           v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  281           clock  59.63Hz
>     480x270 (0xbd) 18.625MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
>           v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.82Hz
>     400x300 (0xbe) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
>           v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
>     400x300 (0xbf) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
>           v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
>     432x243 (0xc0) 16.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   432 start  444 end  484 total  536 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
>           v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  253           clock  59.92Hz
>     432x243 (0xc1) 15.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
>           v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.57Hz
>     320x240 (0xc2) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
>           v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
>     360x202 (0xc3) 11.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   360 start  372 end  404 total  448 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
>           v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  211           clock  59.51Hz
>     360x202 (0xc4) 10.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
>           v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.13Hz
>     320x180 (0xc5)  9.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   320 start  332 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
>           v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  188           clock  59.84Hz
>     320x180 (0xc6)  8.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
>           h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
>           v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.32Hz

[My driver settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHrl.png)

[My graphic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S2fl.png)

Then also there were some times, where I got still pictures on the second screen which look similar to this, I couldn't find a pattern, sometimes if I changed the settings, it would look like that, sometimes not:
[Weird screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuSM.jpg)

**What I have already tries:**

- Configuring the display via xrandr, changed nothing
- I have tried reinstalling the nvidia driver

Also I wanted to add, that this monitor is 21:9, I don't know if there are some known issues for 21:9 monitors or something. Also the monitor works perfectly fine in Windows.
Hoping to get this fixed soon, thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: I have the same problem.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-440/+bug/1871721

And I didn't find the answer. If anyone knows why's happening this, please tell us. 
I tried with nouveau drivers and propietary drivers of Nvidia and it doesn't work. Maybe's related with the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, I figured out, sudo prime-select nvidia,then check by prime-select query,and if it return nvidia, reboot.
After that check settings->details for which graphics card you are using .
That solved my problem.